# Get javascript calculation result as plain text?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a javascript calculation and want to deliver the result as a plain text including the result.value.

However I just managed to do this in a `<input>`form.

This is my code:

Javascript:

```
function doSum() {
   var schritthoehe = document.getElementById("schritthoehe").value;
   var sum = schritthoehe * 0.66;

   document.getElementById("ergebnis").value = sum;
   }
```

Html:

```
<body>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<input type="text" id="schritthoehe">
<input type="button" value="Summieren" onClick="doSum();">
Ergebnis: <input type="text" id="ergebnis" disabled>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Don't forget that `document.getElementById("schritthoehe").value` is a string, not a number.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans `*` makes coercion

Comment: @margsenjo try to create span and then use textContent of the span

Comment: Do you realize that you can convert any number to a string at any time either by calling `sum.toString()` or even just `"" + sum`?  This happens for you automatically when you assign a numeric value to an `<input>` value.

Comment: While `<string> * <number>` indeed coerces, things can go wrong because the `type` for that input field is `text`, not `number`, so an accidental content with letters will do unexpected things (`"a"*4` is NaN, for instance), which you can prevent by first properly converting the string to a number, and only doing the actual math when you know the input really *was* a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To output the result in plain text instead of using an input element, you can use a `span` and set its `textContent`. Following is an example.

Previous solution used `innerHTML`, but I did some research and found that `textContent` is more semantic and offers slightly better performance.

**Working Live Demo:**

```js
function doSum() {
    var schritthoehe = document.getElementById("schritthoehe").value;
    var sum = schritthoehe * 0.66;

    document.getElementById("ergebnis").textContent = sum;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<input type="text" id="schritthoehe">
<input type="button" value="Summieren" onClick="doSum();">
    Ergebnis: <span id="ergebnis"></span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have `ergebnis` be an `output` element, such as an empty `<div id="ergebnis"></div>` and set it's `.textContent` property, that's probably the closest you can get:

```
function doSum() {
   var schritthoehe = document.getElementById("schritthoehe").value;
   var sum = schritthoehe * 0.66;

   document.getElementById("ergebnis").textContent = sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if that's what you seek.

But you can use the function innerHTML:

document.getElementById("div-id").innerHTML = sum;

Answer (score 0):

**Its very easy using Jquery**

```js
function doSum() {
        var schritthoehe = $("#schritthoehe").val();
        var sum = schritthoehe * 0.66;

        $("#ergebnis").html(sum);
        // if you want the value inside the input box then 
        $("#ergebnis_input").val(sum)
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" id="schritthoehe">
    <input type="button" value="Summieren" onClick="doSum();">
        Ergebnis: <span id="ergebnis"></span><input type="text" id="ergebnis_input" readonly>
    </form>
```